# React functional component does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-hooks

Using React I'm building a list of movie cards.

On the card hover, an icon to favorite the movie is shown. Once that icon is clicked, the movie is favorite and the icon is replaced by another icon which indicates that the movie is already favorite:

[image]

**versus**

[image]

The problem is that in order for this to happen, the browser has to be reloaded (although React Profiler from DevTools shows that the card is re-render after its icon is clicked). How to fix it so that the icon should be replaced right away after it is clicked?

`<Card />` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { selectMovie, isMoviePageOpened } from '../../../main.actions';
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder';
import { Grid, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import noImage from '../../../images/no-image-available.png';
import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import useStyles from './Card.styles';
import { RootState } from '../../../store';
import { CardProps } from './Card.types';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import { getUserName, isUserLoggedIn as isCurrentUserLoggedIn } from '../../../utils/common.utils';
import { favouriteMovie, removeFavouriteMovie } from '../../../utils/movies.utils';
const posterBaseUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300';

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ card }: CardProps) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    const favouriteMovies = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.profile.favouriteMovies);

    const isProfilePageOpened = String(pathname.split('/').pop()) === 'profile' ? true : false;
    const isUserLoggedIn = isCurrentUserLoggedIn();
    const isMovieFaved = favouriteMovies.includes(card.id);
    const currentUser = getUserName();

    const changeIsMovieFavourite = () => {
        isMovieFaved ? removeFavouriteMovie(currentUser, card.id) : favouriteMovie(currentUser, card.id);
    };

    const SetSelectedMovieId = (movieId: number) => {
        dispatch(isMoviePageOpened(true));
        dispatch(selectMovie(movieId));
    };
    console.log(card.id, 'isMovieFaved ', isMovieFaved);
    return (
        <Grid item key={card.id}>
            <div className="card-container" onClick={() => SetSelectedMovieId(card.id)}>
                <NavLink to={'/movie/' + card.id} data-testid="catalog-card">
                    <img
                        className={isProfilePageOpened ? classes.profileCard : classes.primaryCard}
                        alt={'Poster of ' + card.title}
                        src={
                            card.poster_path
                                ? card.poster_path.includes('.jpg')
                                    ? posterBaseUrl + card.poster_path
                                    : noImage
                                : noImage
                        }
                        title={card.title}
                    />
                </NavLink>
                <div className="card-details">
                    <IconButton className="fav-icon" onClick={changeIsMovieFavourite}>
                        <NavLink to={isUserLoggedIn ? '' : '/login'} className="fav-icon-button">
                            {isMovieFaved ? <FavoriteIcon /> : <FavoriteBorderIcon />}
                        </NavLink>
                    </IconButton>
                    <div className="vote-average">{card.vote_average}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

`<CatalogCards />` component which iterates over `<Card />`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Grid, CardMedia } from '@material-ui/core';
import '../../../App.scss';
import loadingSpinner from '../../../images/loading-spinner.gif';
import useIntersectionObserver from '../../../customHooks/useIntersectionObserver';
import { changePageSrolledTill } from '../../../main.actions';
import { fetchAllMovies, Movie } from '../../../services/movies.services';
import { showMoviesAtHomePage } from '../../../main.actions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Card from '../../GeneralComponents/Card/Card';
import useStyles from './CatalogCards.styles';
import { RootState } from '../../../store';
import { textConstants } from '../../../constants';

const CatalogCards: React.FC = () => {
    const loadingRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const entry = useIntersectionObserver(loadingRef, {});
    const isVisible = !!entry?.isIntersecting;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const movies = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.movies.homePageMovies);
    const searchedMovie = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.movies.searchedMovie);
    const pageSrolledTill = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.movies.pageSrolledTill);
    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isVisible) {
            if (pageSrolledTill <= 500) {
                dispatch(changePageSrolledTill(pageSrolledTill + 1));

                fetchAllMovies(String(pageSrolledTill))
                    .then(nextPage => {
                        dispatch(showMoviesAtHomePage([...movies, ...nextPage]));
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        dispatch(showMoviesAtHomePage([...movies]));
                    });
            }
        }
    }, [isVisible]);

    return (
        <div>
            {movies.length > 0 && movies.length < 6 && (
                <div className={classes.searchResultsTitle}>{textConstants.MOVIES_FOUND}</div>
            )}
            {movies.length > 0 ? (
                <Grid container className={classes.container}>
                    {movies
                        .filter((movie: Movie) => movie.vote_average !== 0)
                        .map((movie: Movie) => (
                            <Card key={movie.id} card={movie} />
                        ))}
                </Grid>
            ) : searchedMovie ? (
                <div className={classes.noResultsMessage}>{textConstants.TRY_DIFFERENT_PHRASE}</div>
            ) : (
                <CardMedia component="img" image={loadingSpinner} className={classes.loadingSpinner} />
            )}
            {!searchedMovie && (
                <div ref={loadingRef}>{pageSrolledTill <= 500 ? '' : textConstants.ALL_MOVIES_SEEN}</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default CatalogCards;
```

favouriteMovie() function:

```
export const favouriteMovie = async (currentUser: string, movieId: number) => {
    const userData = {
        userName: currentUser,
        movie: movieId,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8082/favouritemovie/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
    }).then(async response => {
        const res = await response.json();

        if (response.status === 200) {
            return;
        } else {
            return res.errorMsg;
        }
    });
};
```

removeFavouriteMovie() function:

```
export const removeFavouriteMovie = async (currentUser: string, movieId: number) => {
    const userData = {
        userName: currentUser,
        movie: movieId,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8082/removefavouritemovie/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
    }).then(async response => {
        const res = await response.json();

        if (response.status === 200) {
            return;
        } else {
            return res.errorMsg;
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do `favouriteMovie()` and `removeFavouriteMovie` correctly update the structure? I have the feeling that you mutate the structure, instead of updating it in a non-mutating manner. This can cause the view not update, since the base object still has the same identity React might think nothing has changed. Could you share the code for `favouriteMovie()` and `removeFavouriteMovie()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if favouriteMovie() and removeFavouriteMovie correctly update the structure, I have shared the code of these 2 functions

Comment: The problem could be caused by the card keys, just make sure `card.id` is unique for each element. And a little advice for cleaner code, try using less inline conditional rendering.

Comment: I've made sure the cards' keys are unique, it seems the keys don't cause the issue. Also, thanks for your suggestion regarding inline conditional rendering. Can you tell me what would be a getter alternative to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API calls should be in a [Redux Thunk](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) which then dispatch to the store to update the list of movies setting whether or not it is favorited.

```
export const removeFavouriteMovie = (request) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8082/favouritemovie/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(request),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // New reducer to unfavorite the movie
        dispatch(unfavoriteMovie(request.movie));
      } else {
        // New reduce to notify the user of the error
        const res = await response.json();
        dispatch(setErrorMessage(`There was a problem saving the movie: ${res.errorMsg}`);
      }
    };
}
```

Then this function should be updated to use dispatch to call the thunk.

```
const changeIsMovieFavourite = () => {
  isMovieFaved ?
  dispatch(removeFavouriteMovie({ userName: currentUser, movie: card.id }) :
  dispatch(favouriteMovie({userName: currentUser, movie: card.id});
};
```

Just know that if the API call takes a while the user may think they didn't un-favorite the movie so you might want to toggle the Heart fill in the component and then if it succeeds the heart fill stays empty but if an error shows up the user gets the error message and the heart fill goes back to solid.

Comment: useMemo() hook is used to prevent unnecessary re-renders. The issue I'm trying to solve is different - I would like favorited card to be re-rendered and new icons displayed

Comment: I'm going to update my answer because I think I see the issue.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, many thanks! Previously I haven't heard of Redux Thunk so your answer was helpful indeed!